# How to resolve System.Zip.TZipFile.ExtractAll not extracting all data from .zip file?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm using Embarcadero C++Builder 10.1 Berlin Update 2.  I'm using `System.Zip.TZipFile.ExtractAll()` to extract a large `.zip` file.

Here are the details surrounding the problem scenario:

- The size of the `.zip` file is 387,077 KB
- Using `System.Zip.TZipFile.ExtractAll()` to extract the `.zip` file, we end up with:

  - a 4,194,304 KB size file.
  - The data is truncated.
- Using Windows OS, right click `Extract All...`, we end up with

  - a 6,035,259 KB size file.

We need all of the data out of this file.

Reading the [System.Zip.TZipFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Zip.TZipFile) documentation, I do not see anything about limitations related to file size.

From what I know, this is Embarcadero's provided way to extract `.zip` files.  How may I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you know if it has flushed everything to the disk? Assuming running on Windows OS do equivalent of `sync`

Comment: @Griffin I'm sure it's my ignorance, what do you mean flushed everything to disk? The extraction method call is wrapped in `Synchronize()` which is supposed to ensure that it runs on the main thread.

Comment: In Linux based OS `sync` ensures everything outstanding in memory is flushed to flash. I think in Windows you may have something like `FlushFileBuffers` which may do a similar thing. Of course this may not be the cause of the issue but do check.

Comment: The original zip format had to be extended to support large files.  Called zip64 in the appnote.txt spec.  A quicky Google for "tzipfile zip64" takes you to [this forum post](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=705097).  So what you see is normal.  Keep looking and you'll find people that fixed the restriction, like [CERN did](https://root.cern.ch/root/html534/TZIPFile.html).

Comment: There are plenty of 3rd party ZIP libraries/components available that are far better than `TZipFile`.  I suggest you use one of them.  `TZipFile` has had alot of problems over the years. It is not a very reliable class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you tell us whether the data are simply truncated or instead somehow transformed, we can only really guess at what is going on. However, it's a well-educated guess.

Your output is precisely 2<sup>32</sup> bytes long, a familiar boundary for many older technologies.

The fact that (as you point out) the documentation doesn't state this limit, further suggests that this is just an upper bound on what the developers bothered to support, probably a very long time ago. They never imagined you'd need any more than that, particularly as many file systems didn't even support files larger than that until [relatively] recently.

Prefer modern, standard C++ and a nice third-party library for unzipping.

Comment: The data is truncated; I updated the post to include this information. At this time, I agree with your answer.

Comment: `TZipFile` was introduced in XE2 in 2011. Large `.zip` files have been around a lot longer than that, and Windows has supported large files > 4GB ever since NTFS was first introduced in NT3. Embarcadero simply didn't bother implementing support for the ZIP64 format (and still haven't) when they created `TZipFile`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Fair enough.